# Duas páginas usando o mesmo Servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlet

Tenho minha página principal(index.jsp) utiliza o servlet para algumas pequenas coisas. Então redireciona para a página final.jsp.
Essa página irá utilizar o servlet também, pois preciso que o usuário escolha as funções (botões) que ele quer usar.
Minha pergunta é:
Posso utilizar o mesmo servlet ou tenho que criar um para cada botão?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É possível usar o mesmo Servlet para várias ações.

Uma forma simples é colocar um atributo `name` em cada botão e então verificar dentro Servlet, nos parâmetros de *request*, qual botão foi pressionado. Haverá um atributo com o mesmo `name` do botão apertado.

O maior problema dessa abordagem é acabar com um código espagueti, isto é, vários `ifs`  tratando coisas diferentes num mesmo método. Resumindo, atente para a a organização do código, mais do que com a preocupação de ter mais classes e métodos.

Se não for um projeto trivial, considere um framework como o Spring MVC para facilitar seu trabalho.

Comment: e como faço a verificação nos parametro do request??

Comment: `String str = request.getParameter("foo");` - basta fazer a comparação com a string.